# Excel to sql table error Msg 7350

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, t-sql, openrowset

I'm using this code for import an excel file into a sql table

```
USE master
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;

 RECONFIGURE;
 GO

  sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;

   RECONFIGURE;
   GO

insert into memberform (id)
    SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\\test.xls;HDR=YES', 'select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

But I'm getting error:

> Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" >for linked server "(null)".

Is there something I should parametrize first in sql?

Comment: Docs: "OPENROWSET does not accept variables for its arguments." You need to follow the steps in the message.

Comment: Please don't use any spaces in the `OPENROWSET` command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, I just installed AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 bit. Cause My sql is 64 bit and my office 32 bit thats why it didnt worked.The problem is that you cant install Access Database Engine x64 on office 2007 32bit. You will need this instructions: https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-civil-3d/troubleshooting/caas/sfdcarticles/sfdcarticles/How-to-install-64-bit-Microsoft-Database-Drivers-alongside-32-bit-Microsoft-Office.html

Also in my code i should use ace insted of jet.Also because i'm using excel 2007 i need to change it to excel 12.0. Like the example below

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET ('Microsoft.Ace.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=C:\\test.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'select * from [Sheet1$]')
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, `Ad hoc Distributed Queries` are disabled by default in SQL Server due to security configuration and you cannot use either `OPENROWSET` or `OPENDATASOURCE` and if you cannot execute these rowset functions, then you cannot access any remote data sources.

Run the following queries to enable these options to let you work on these without any further issues:

```
USE master
GO
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;

RECONFIGURE;
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;

RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

From the output, you could see that the "Ad hoc Distributed Queries" setting changed from 0 to 1. Now you can easily execute any `Ad hoc Query`

**Note**: By default, this option is set to 0 and you need to change it to 1 to activate this feature.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you it works but now i get two errors: Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Generally such errors are encountered due to incorrect file name or file not being available for use. Do you mind restarting your SQL Server instance and then check if it works?

Comment: Error MSG:Msg 7350, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot get the column information from OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" >for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Microsoft [documentation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error/) suggests this corrective action for your problem - **Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly**

Comment: If you are able to resolve your issues, consider accepting the answer!